# Hook user register action

Tags: 7, hooks

How to hook user registration page? Basically I want to save some cookies when user comes on the register page through an affiliate link. I used `hook_user_view` but it is working only when user is logged in. Can someone please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement `hook_form_alter()` and check `$form_id == 'user_register_form'`